# Why my ProgressBar is showing up after inline coroutine function, instead of before?

Tags: kotlin, inline, coroutine, android-progressbar, fuel

When I'm sending HTTP requests to server from my tablet by using Fuel, I want to display a ProgressBar at screen before the concerned function begins to run. But for an unknow reason, it's happened once the function has completed its job.

The ProgressBar is defined programmatically by this function :

```
protected fun initProgressBar(constraintLayoutID: Int): ProgressBar {
        val originalConstraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(constraintLayoutID)
        progressBar = ProgressBar(this).apply {
            id = getInteger(R.integer.INT_PROGRESS_BAR_ID)
            elevation = 999F
            isIndeterminate = true
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300, 300)
            visibility = View.GONE

            originalConstraintLayout.addView(this)
        }

        ConstraintSet().run {
            clone(originalConstraintLayout)

            for(position in listOf(ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM))
                connect(progressBar!!.id, position, constraintLayoutID, position,0)
            applyTo(originalConstraintLayout)
        }
        return progressBar!!
    }
```

I've tried to show/hide the `ProgressBar` lonely and it's working perfectly. Here is the inline function where it should be showed before sending the main request :

```
inline fun <reified T : DefaultResponse> sendRequest(
        routeName: String = "",
        routeArgs: String = ""
    ): T = runBlocking { // Help : https://fuel.gitbook.io/documentation/support/fuel-coroutines
        owner.runOnUiThread {
            owner.showProgressBar() // Should display at this point, not after
        }

        val adaptedResponse = ResponseFactory.getInstance(owner).getResponseObjectFor(T::class.java.name, routeName)
        val (request, response, result) = Fuel.get(
            "%s%s?%s%s".format(
                networkManager.getURLConnection(),
                (adaptedResponse as DefaultResponse).getRouteName(),
                routeArgs,
                getIndustrialTrypticArgs()
            )
        ).awaitObjectResponseResult(adaptedResponse)

        val exception =
            FailedRequestException(owner.getString(R.string.STR_EXCEPTION_RM_FAILED_REQUEST)).apply {
                setHTTPMessage(response.responseMessage)
                setStatusCode(response.statusCode)
                setUsedRequest(request.url)
            }

        return@runBlocking result.fold<T>(
            { responseObject ->
                if (response.statusCode != 200)
                    throw exception
                return@fold responseObject as T
            },
            { error ->
                throw exception.setOriginalError(error.exception)
            }
        )
    }
```

Also, I've added a call to `runOnUiThread` for the display, with an encapsulation in a different coroutine thread with `launch` at some point, but it didn't work (still appearing after the execution's end of the inline function).

It's because it's an inline function ? Or there's a concern about concurrent threads ?

**UPDATE N°1**

Following Tenfour04's advices, I changed the `sendRequest` into a suspend function :

```
suspend inline fun <reified T : DefaultResponse> sendRequest(
        routeName: String = "",
        routeArgs: String = "",
        isBlocking: Boolean = true
    ): T? {
        val adaptedResponse = ResponseFactory.getInstance(owner).getResponseObjectFor(T::class.java.name, routeName) // 1
        val fuelRequest = Fuel.get( // 2
            "%s%s?%s%s".format(
                networkManager.getURLConnection(),
                (adaptedResponse as DefaultResponse).getRouteName(),
                routeArgs,
                getIndustrialTrypticArgs()
            )
        )
        var fuelResponse: T? = null // 3

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            owner.showProgressBar() // 4
        }
        try {
            fuelResponse =
                if(isBlocking) {
                    val answer = fuelRequest.awaitObjectResponseResult(adaptedResponse) // 5

                    treatsResponse(answer) as T // 6
                }
                else {
                    fuelRequest.responseObject(adaptedResponse) { httpRequest, httpResponse, httpResult ->
                        try {
                            treatsResponse(httpRequest, httpResponse, httpResult) as T
                        }
                        catch (e: FailedRequestException) {
                            println(e.getOriginalError())
                            println(e.getUsedRequest())
                        }
                        finally {
                            owner.hideProgressBar()
                        }
                    }
                    null
                }
        }
        catch (e: FailedRequestException) {
            println(e.getOriginalError())
            println(e.getUsedRequest())
        }
        finally {
            owner.hideProgressBar()
        }
        return fuelResponse
    }
```

The call of `sendRequest` is encapsulated into a `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch`. It's an improvement since the `ProgressBar` begins to appear within the function and not after its call, but I still want that it display before the `fuelRequest.awaitObjectResponseResult(adaptedResponse)` line (`// 5`).

`awaitObjectResponseResult` is also a suspend function.

**UPDATE N°2**

While a line-per-line debug session, I remarked the following on `sendRequest` : when `owner.showProgressBar()` is encapsulated into `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` (`// 4`), it's clearly executed after `// 5`th instruction.

So, the actual order of execution since the beginning is always `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6`.

When I add `Dispatchers.Main` as the second argument of `awaitObjectResponseResult`, the order become `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 4`. It looks like this function always get the priority for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

`runOnUiThread` is asynchronous. Since you want the behavior to be *synchronous*, meaning in the order the code appears, you should use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` instead.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    owner.showProgressBar()
}
```

`withContext` is a suspend function that can change which thread the inner code is run on synchronously.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't work : once sendRequest's call is make, app is freezing ; debugger can't even reach the "owner.showProgressBar".

Here's logs I got when it's freezing :

I/fasthttpclient: Thread[6,tid=5892,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7900861000,peer=0x13c40028,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/fasthttpclient: 
I/fasthttpclient: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

Comment: You can’t call this function from the main thread since it’s blocking for a long time. I was assuming you had a good reason for using `runBlocking` that I don’t know about because I don’t use Fuel. This whole function should be marked `suspend` with the `runBlocking` removed from around its contents. Wherever you are calling it from, you should `launch` a coroutine to call it and work with its return value.

Comment: The only place you should ever use `runBlocking` is in a non-spending callback function you are overriding for a library that doesn’t support coroutines and guarantees is calling the callback off the main thread.

Comment: Actually, using `runBlock`  was just because I can't use the `awaitObjectResponseResult` method in the main thread (a fuel-coroutines' restriction) and I would try quickly if the exchanges with the server were working. I'll replace it with coroutine calls as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it appears that Fuel has an open issue with native [Java's async IO API](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/issues/804). Whatever I've tried so far just can't work on the main thread since Fuel's method `awaitObjectResponseResult` blocks it completely until it have been called. Apparently, this issue will be fixed in the next major update.